# Kubuntu 23.04 sound only working on certain applications

Tags: sound, kubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa

One day just lost audio on most programs. Still working on Brave browser and some games but nothing else. So Alsa working fine on firmware level but appears to be Pulseaudio issue. Tried doing stop and restart but did not fix problem. Will removing Pulseaudio be a workaround or should just upgrade to 23.10 when available?

Well, upgraded to 23.10 but still have problem. This is what i have tried
sudo service pulseaudio restart

pulseaudio --start

sudo apt --reinstall pipewire-media-session

sudo apt --reinstall install pipewire-media-session

without any success. i am mostly a newbie beginner so am not a techno expert. Any help from anyone would be appreciated